# Why equals returns false in my java code?

Tags: java, equals

I do not understand why **equals()** returns "false" instead of "true" in my code ?

```
class Location {

    private int x, y;

    public Location(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Location a = new Location(1, 2); //
        Location b = new Location(1, 2); // same values

        System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // result : "false"
    }
}
```

How to compare the values of two objects ?

Comment: You need to override the equals() method. You should also do the same for hashcode()

Comment: And BTW, java.awt.Point is essentially the same as your class here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding `equals()` method is like a routine. You can use IDE tools to generate `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Location other = (Location) obj;
        if (!getEnclosingInstance().equals(other.getEnclosingInstance()))
            return false;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Override the base 'equals' method with this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Location that = (Location) o;
    return x.equals(that.x) &&
      y.equals(that.y);
}
```

Comment: But you can't do `.equals()` on primitive `int`s, can you?

Comment: Is that introduced in a newer version of Java than 8? My compiler says, `Cannot invoke equals(int) on the primitive type int'`.

Comment: @FredLarson I guess best practice would be == then. It used to allow you to use .equals() to compare ints in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

This method is defined in the Object class so that every Java object inherits it. By default, its implementation compares object memory addresses, so it works the same as the == operator. However, we can override this method in order to define what equality means for our objects.

You Should override override the equals() method for this class so that we can compare two Locations based on their internal details:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Location that = (Location) o;
        return x.equals(that.x) &&
          y.equals(that.y);
    }
```